# Wither skeleton spawning

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can I make a wither skeleton farm in the over world? Or does it have to be in a nether fortress. Just wondering because I’m trying to get a stack of nether stars

Answer (score 1):

As @Topcode said, wither skeletons only spawn inside nether fortresses. There are, however, designs for farms that you can build in the nether.